# JQuery UI dialog popup - Add a wrapper about div

Tags: jquery, html, css

The following is my code.

```
_createWrapper: function () {
        this.uiDialog = $("<div>")
        .addClass("popup_overlay" + this.options.dialogClass )
        this.uiDialog = $("<div>")
            .addClass( "ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front " +
                this.options.dialogClass )
            .hide()
            .attr({
                // Setting tabIndex makes the div focusable
                tabIndex: -1,
                role: "dialog"
            })
            .appendTo( this._appendTo() );
```

I have added this code from my side :

```
this.uiDialog = $("<div>")
.addClass("popup_overlay" + this.options.dialogClass )
```

How can I add wrapper div above this div?

```
this.uiDialog = $("<div>")
                .addClass( "ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front "
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following snippet in your code, it'll do the rest

```
.wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

i.e.

```
this.uiDialog = $("<div>").addClass("ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front")..wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

Comment: no brother i want new div above this div > ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable

Comment: @shakil If you don't mind could you please create a fiddle and share it?

Comment: i have done with this code $(".ui-dialog").wrap("<div class='popup_overlay'></div>"); can anyone but problem is it is not working if i use this in this way     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".ui-dialog").wrap("<div class='popup_overlay'></div>");
    </script> but it is working if i past and enter it in console, please anyone can tell me how i can use this code

Comment: @shakil That's why I told you to create a fiddle, so we'll come to know what problem is, now the solution for your problem is write css for <div class='popup_overlay'></div>

Comment: i have css created for this .popup_overlay 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -21px;
} in style.css file

Comment: @shakil seriously, could please create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ or a pen on http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: People forget this question :- Please tell me is there any plugin that i can click on it so it will open a popup window and in that popup i can see the content just like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smart-jQuery-Pan-Zoom-Plugin-Smart-jQuery-Zoom/example/ In short I want this functionality in popup. Please help me.

Comment: @shakil so you want zoom in & zoom out in pop up?